# Aero: "Close programs using mirror drives" - How can I see what programs are causing the problem?

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop, aero

I've closed Remote Administrator and disabled Remote Administrator. I don't know what else could be causing this. Is there a way to find what programs are "using mirror drives"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume this is a Mirror **Driver** and not a mirror drive.  Cause drives wouldn't cause Windows Aero to complain.  Now a Mirror driver is a special display driver used in VNC software and the JAWS reader.  Mirror drivers, however, are incompatible with Vista/7 DWM.

What have you installed on your PC recently that might fall under the catagories of VNC, display drivers or or JAWS reader? If you need the software, I'm afraid you are out of luck unless there is an updated version of the software.  If not, you can uninstall the software and driver.  Your call.
edit: Here is what finally worked.

We can always give device manager a try. Your mirror driver would be listed under display adapters. Disable it, but leave it installed and see what happens.

Comment: The problem is that I cannot figure out what program is using this mirror drive*r*. I just got the new computer (laptop), and I don't think Aero has been enabled at all.

Comment: Right click your desktop and hit personalize. You can tell if aero is selected or not.  If it isn't here should be a prompt that should help trouble shoot.  If not, hit F3 and type "Performance." The Performance tools should show up in your search results. Click that. there should be a link to start the automatic troubleshooting. It should give you an exact reason. If that STILL DOESN'T work, you can force it by restarting the Windows Experience Index.

Comment: That's the diagnostic tool I've been running. And it doesn't give me any details. I tried reindexing, but that didn't report any problems, and the diagnostic message remain the same. But I just noticed that the details for the error notes a *potentional* issue: "Aero effects not supported on this Windows edition" - Could the problem actually be my display driver having problems for x64 and not a mirrored driver at all..?

Comment: This Windows edition? That makes me want to ask, what edition do you have?

Comment: You can also try forcing it by going under "Services.msc" and starting the DWM (which I forgot what it stands for...).

Comment: Win7 Enterprise x64. Restarted DWM and reran the diagnostics - same problem. Also tried related troubleshooters, but I only found one that didn't detect any problems (Display Quality)

Comment: Odd. We can always give device manager a try.  Your mirror driver would be listed under display adapters. Disable it, but leave it installed and see what happens. BTW, what kind of video card is on the laptop?

Comment: Thanks! I think you just found my problem! I need a restart to be sure though. Remote Adminitrator has installed a Mirror Driver, and it's obviously enough for windows that the program and background service is closed/stopped for Aero to work. Mind writing your tips as an answer so I can accept it? Rebooting :)

Comment: More cut and paste. I'm just gonna add it to the existing answer.